# Zend Framework - Class Names - Change Defualt Rules :: How Can be Zend application be configured for more short class names without folders names?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

In zend project have rules default for calling classes that say to put folder class structure before class name.

Example: **class Application_Model_DbTable_Albums** means:
 that this class inside folders: Application->Model->DBTable, 
if its called Just **class Albums**  he will be unrecognized.

How Can be Zend application be configured for more short class without folder location names only class name like **class Album** and not **class Application_Model_DbTable_Albums**?

Thank you,

Yosef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you were to [disable the Zend Autoloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029296/disable-zend-autoloader) and handle this manually (or with a different autoload mechanism), I believe you're stuck.

You could move some of your classes up in structure, however. Our models (e.g. Model_Album) live at application/models/Album.php.

Comment: Must be other way like change settings of Zend

Comment: @Yosef: If you say `new Album()` Zend will look in certain areas for that class. You can debug through to see where the autoloader is looking (if you're using it) or simple tell it via your include_once or require_once statement.

Comment: Ok, I know that but I looking for method that  used but many, and if his not exist (Until know its looks like that) - I think Zend Framework has problem of design or also in other frameworks is same

Comment: @Yosef, I'm sure the Zend community would be interested in your concerns but based on my experiences with them it seems as if they're intending some formal structure in order to keep Zend as a framework and not just a library. That's a guess however.

Comment: Is it the same with rubi on reils or django? (I dont know this frameworks)

Answer (score 1):

You can "use" that way, but you need to "require" each class in your code so they are available on the scope of your script, that way they don't pass via the Autoloader.